# android xml Textview text attribute cannot take '<' as value

Tags: android, xml, text

I cannot type

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/del"
        android:text="<"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

it gives an error

> Error:(317) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: you can set text programmatically

Comment: dont want to use java for this actualy :/ there must be some way?

Comment: try this
&lt;  instead of  < and
&gt; instead of    >

Comment: try: `android:text="&lt;"`

Comment: where can i find all these values?

Comment: It's HTML entities. Just google for a complete list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this in the XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/del"
    android:text="&lt;"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Programmatically:

```
button.setText("<");
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape your text, the xml has particularities regarding escape text check this link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

So, in your case replace `"<"` for `"&lt;"`

```
&quot;   "
&amp;    &
&apos;   '
&lt;     <
&gt;     >
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want set ">" character in XML file you can do by following ways

1) By using **CDATA** you can achieve this.

2) Dynamically you can set to button as follows

```
yourButton.setText("<");
```

or you can use

```
android:text="&lt;"
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&lt;` for `<`, `&gt;` for `>` and `&amp;` for `&`.

Please create string in your value folder.

```
<string name="lessThanSymbol">&lt;</string>
```

And use like this-

```
android:text="@string/lessThanSymbol"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.You just have to set the height & width. Just Copy and paste this code in your xml.

```
    <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/del"
               android:text="<"
               android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```